# Preventing Excel from automatically creating a range when entering + or * in formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Often, when I am entering formulas in Excel 2010, as soon as I enter a cell reference, and then a + or * to add or multiply things together, Excel will make some kind of correction that creates a range, which I then have to delete to continue entering my formula.

For example: I'm trying to enter the formula:

```
$U$2 * (C2 + J2 * $W$2 / 2)
```

This weird feature didn't trigger on the first *, but as soon as I entered the plus after C2, Excel changed the + to +2:2, and the whole 2nd row was suddenly selected as a range.

```
$U$2 * (C2 +2:2
```

What causes this range feature to happen, and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Shift` + `Space` selects the current row.

What you are doing is holding `Shift` while pressing `Space`. So when you are entering * you are probably still holding `Shift` to type "(" but you press `Space` and the row gets selected.

Best thing to do would be to not enter spaces between operators, as Excel does not need them. This will let you continue to hold `Shift` while typing your formula. Else you'll have to let go of `Shift` before pressing `Space`.